# Google App Engine : print "self.request.path"

Tags: google-app-engine

When I `self.response.out.write(self.request.path)` the output is something like `\page\cfg%27%40`.

How do I print out the character instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have do something like this

```
import urllib2
path = self.request.path
unquoted_path=urllib2.unquote(path)
```